React optimize image loading
I'm developing a web game using ReactJs. It uses quite a lot of images and when trying to visit some page on first time it takes some time to load all the images. Is there a way to preload all images beforehand, so that after app launches it shows images instantly?
I've already tried some ways of image preloading (e.g.https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-preload-ptosn?file=/src/App.js) but they don't seem to work as they still take some time to show image.

you can try using webp file format to load images those are lightweight images

You can try to using the react-image package and lazy load concepts and webp file format for image optimization.

Solution 1:
Tell the browser to preload all the images you will need during the game on page load. You can do that by adding a <link> tag with rel="preload" for each of your images in the page <head>:
<head>
    <link rel="preload" href="path/to/image1.jpg" as="image">
    <link rel="preload" href="path/to/image2.jpg" as="image">
</head>

This is a very simple approach, but it does not allow you to show a loader while the game loads.
Solution 2:
Preload the images using Javascript's Image objects. That way, you can detect the onload and onerror events of these images and update the UI based on the result.  Here is an example hook you can use:
function usePreloadImages(imageUrls) {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    let loadedCount = 0;
    const totalCount = imageUrls.length;

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
    
        imageUrls.forEach((url) => {
            const img = new Image();

            img.onload = () => {
                loadedCount += 1;
                if (loadedCount === totalCount) {
                    setIsLoading(false);
                }
            };

            img.src = url;
        });
    })

    return isLoading;
}

An image loaded this way will be automatically cached by the browser, and will immediately show if an <img> tag references it later.

The first solution works. Thank you!
